# JWrapper - JVM Options on launch

Tags: jwrapper

I'm experimenting with using JWrapper to create executable's for a Java application. I see we can set JVM options when we create the wrapper, but can you/how do you set the JVM options dynamically, post install, when launching?

For instance, on a x32 machine we want to use -Xmx1536m but on a x64 machine we want -Xmx4096m.

Further more, depending on application demands, one user may want/need a larger stack size so we need to set -Xss dynamically.  Can this parameter be passed in some how to the executable? Or can we use one virtual app to launch another virtual app using programmable JVM options?